# .pick not supported on a Mix?

Tags: syntax, raku

I am trying this:

```perl6
 my Mix $mix = { foo => 3.5, bar => 2.5}.Mix; 
 say $mix.pick
```

Which should theoretically work, since [a Mix does Baggy](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Mix#(Baggy)_method_pick), and [Baggy does pick](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Mix#(Baggy)_method_pick). However, I get the error:

```perl6
.pick is not supported on a Mix
```

Any idea why it's not supported? What alternative should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any idea why it's not supported?

Perhaps:

```
lizmat     TimToady: .pick($n > 1) on a MixHash, how would that work? I assume it won't work? What to deduct for a chosen key?
lizmat     (or on a Mix, for that matter)
TimToady   I don't we need to support .pick on a Mix until someone comes up with a real use case
```

From http://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/perl6?date=2013-10-03#l1369

> What alternative should I use?

I suspect it's "write your own".